# Order multiple sorted arrays

Tags: python, arrays

This is an interesting problem:

I have sorted arrays

```
a1 : [50,30,20,5]
a2 : [30,10,3,1]
a3 : [50,40,30,10]
```

Each array is sorted, I need to arrange the array in order of which array has the highest number, if there's a tie consider next element in array.

Ex. In above example 50 is tie between a1 and a3 so we compare 30 and 40 hence the order is

a3,a1,a2

How to do this in python? What should be the algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: The algorithm is called "lexicographical order", by analogy with human-language dictionaries. To decide whether `and` comes before or after `aardvark`, you compare the first letter, they're both `a`, so you compare the second letter, and `n` comes after `a`, so you have your answer. Just replace "letter" with "list element" and it's the same algorithm you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Comparing two lists in Python compares elements like that by default, so all you have to do is put your lists in a list and sort it.

```
my_arrays = [
    [50,30,20,5],
    [30,10,3,1],
    [50,40,30,10]
]

my_arrays.sort(reverse=True)

print my_arrays
```

Result:

```
[
    [50, 40, 30, 10], 
    [50, 30, 20, 5], 
    [30, 10, 3, 1]
]
```